# Phone Gap: Local Storage in Android

Tags: cordova

we had set local storage in phone gap environment  like  `localStorage.a=a`. if i want to use/get that local storage in android  so can we get it! if yes then how ?

Comment: Please clarify: where did you set this `localStorage.a=a` and in with what kind of code do you need to get it? In a Java app for Android? "use/get that local storage in android" sounds unclear.

Comment: @Savoo check out this link for more info - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/storage/localstorage/localstorage.html you can also make use of local storage plugin to ease up things

Comment: @YakovL Yes i create phone gap with android plateform. and localstorage.a =a syntax of cordova and i use it in cordova code but for some cases i need this local storage value in java app code (MainActivity OR Service) .so how can i get this localstorage value ?

Answer (score 0):

we found Solution!a
Use this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativestorage

to get share value between cordova and java(Android)

it's working!